# how to get value of added file uploaded value by using request.form in MVC Razor?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

how to get value of added file uploaded value by using request.form in MVC Razor? i can not access "fileTypeInput" value. Look please screenshot...

```
        <span class="btn green fileinput-button">
            <i class="icon-plus icon-white"></i>
            <span>@Html.LocalizeGlobal("Add files...")</span>
            @* <input type="file" id="fileContainer" name="files[]" multiple />*@
            <input type="file"  name="fileTypeInput" value="Upload" />
        </span>

    </div>


   private void FileUpload(Course item)
    {
        var x = (System.Web.HttpPostedFileBase)Request.Files["uploadFile"];
        switch (Request.Form["fileTypeInput"])
        {
            case "Upload":
          . . . .
          . . . . .
        }
   }
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fileTypeInput` will be inside `Request.Files` and not inside `Request.Form`. You seem to have inverted those keys:

```
var x = (System.Web.HttpPostedFileBase)Request.Files["fileTypeInput"];
```

Since your file input has the name `fileTypeInput`, that's the key you should use to retrieve the uploaded file from the `Request.Files` collection. Right now you have used `Request.Files["uploadFile"]` but it is unclear where this `uploadFile` is coming from and whether you have a file input with this name inside your form.

You could also have your controller action take a parameter with the same name:

```
public ActionResult SomeAction(HttpPostedFileBase fileTypeInput)
{
    ...
}
```

this will avoid you the need of casting and also make your action easier to unit test in isolation.